# Trigger javascript function from Django server

Tags: javascript, django

I am working on IPN's. Whenever I receive an IPN in this url: `https://www.mywebsitename.com/notifications`, I would like to run a simple JavaScript function that displays some html content.

I manage the IPN's from the server side, as follows:

```
@csrf_exempt
def notifications(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       #some code
```

I would like to trigger my JS function inside that block of code, but I can't come up with any way of doing this. Also I don't really know wether what I am asking is really possible or not, maybe there is another approach that I can't figure out by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is 100% possible with Django using Websockets. It sounds like you are trying to build a notification system for the UI based on when you receive a request at one of your urls. Start by checking out Django Channels: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

This is the best way to use Websockets with Django, which can help you implement notifications or other real-time features. The tutorial in the docs is great. To solve your task, you should:

- Follow the tutorial and set up a WebSocket consumer in your Django app to handle notifications. This is what will allow a frontend user to establish a real-time connection with your application and receive messages from it.
- Finish your notifications_view. After the request from the payment comes in, you will be dispatching a message to your websocket consumer for whichever user needs to recieve the message. It could end up looking something like this:

```
# assuming that the request gives you the username of the user to be notified,
# and you have a group configured in your consumer

def notification_view(request):
     if request.method == "POST":
          username = request.POST.get('username')
          group_name = 'notifications{}'.format(username)
          channel_layer = channels.layers.get_channel_layer()
          async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
                 group_name,
                 {
                     'type': 'new_payment',
                     'text': {
                         'eventType': 'notification',
                         'name': 'New Payment',
                         'userMessage': 'You just got paid'
                     }
                 }
     return(HttpResponse(status=200))
```

This would send a message over the user's socket when the request is received.

In your js, you will setup a listener for the socket. Then you can listen for the messages and do whatever you desire in the document with the data you recieve, such as show a user a message:

```
var endpoint = 'ws://' + '<yourhost>/notifications/username/;
var socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(endpoint);

socket.onmessage = e => {
     data = JSON.parse(e.data);
     let msg = document.createElement('<p>');
     msg.innerText = data['text']['userMessage'] 
    }
```

Just follow the tutorial and that will certainly get you headed in the right direction!