# How To Add $2 To a User Account Balance Immediately A Post is Viewed on a Django Blog

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, python-requests

*I want Users on my website to be able to Earn from my website immediately they View  a post on my blog website but am finding it difficult to add that feauture to my apps. I want an amount to be added to my website immediately a post is been viewed on clicked on and i have an IP function because i want the action to be once(the amount should be added once).*

**Please take a good look at my models.py for the post**

```
class Post(models.Model):

     title = models.CharField(max_length=160, help_text='Maximum 160 Title characters.')
     summary = models.TextField(max_length=400, help_text='Maximum text of 400 characters can be inserteed here alone' )
     subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
     introduction = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True,)

     content  = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**This is balance.py**

```
class Balance(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    balance = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

**In my models.py i also have a code for my view**

```
#this is used in ordering view count in django views
class PostView(models.Model):
     post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
     ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=False, blank=False)

     class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']
```

**This is the property that counts my views**

```
@property
def view_count(self):
    return PostView.objects.filter(post=self).count()
```

Question Summary

*I Now want $2 to be added to this default balance of every Aunthenticated Users immediately a post is beeing viewed once.*

*That is if a user visit a particular Post on the website then a sum of $2 dollar will automatically be added to their balance immediately they view this post.*
*I want this addition to take place only once and any subsequest view on a single post will not count.*

**Can someone help me out with this code.**

What is the trick of making this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want users to make a new request every time they view a post, this is likely a situation where you need a WebSocket. Ultimately, this is a real-time feature. You will have the client send a message to the server over a WebSocket everytime the user views a post. The message will contain data that will allow you to modify the `Balance` model instance for the user through your WebSocket consumer.

See this answer I wrote on getting started with WebSockets in Django ([Trigger javascript function from Django server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65744556/trigger-javascript-function-from-django-server/65745272#65745272)), but mostly just read Django Channels docs (https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).